# Permission issues with Importing PostgreSQL Dump to RDS

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am trying import a PostgreSQL dump to a new setup DB on RDS. It throws up following error. The solution described in various threads are focusing on alter the current role to superuser which is slightly different on RDS.

`psql:201409021622.sql:23: ERROR:  must be owner of extension plpgsql
CREATE EXTENSION
psql:201409021622.sql:37: ERROR:  must be owner of extension hstore
SET
psql:201409021622.sql:51: ERROR:  type "addbandarg" already exists
ALTER TYPE
COMMENT
psql:201409021622.sql:67: ERROR:  must be superuser to create a base type
psql:201409021622.sql:76: ERROR:  permission denied for language c`

How to resolve this?

Comment: make sure you are connecting to RDS with the username which you have specified at the time of creating RDS. in RDS, this user is equivalent to a Super user and has all the necessary permission.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer Yes it was connected using the same account. I used the typical postgres as the user to avoid conflicts if any.

Answer (score 0):

**RDS does not give you superuser access** at all, ever. The comment on your post is wrong.

The root account you create in RDS is not a superuser. That's the reason you're getting those messages.